# Jsp: can i render out a stringwriter higher than the current writer output?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm used to rails and the very handy yield functionality in erbs. I would like to be able to inject css/js script tags to the head when I'm running through many child jsp templates in the body tag. I know this is possible with Rails using yield, but I cant see a way of injecting a string higher than whats already outputted... here is my example

```
<head>
<!--- i want to inject script tags into here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- running multiple child templates here -->
<!-- when the template needs a script tag, find a way of injecting it into the head -->
</body>
```

can I render into the head tag from further down the page, is this possible in jsp using string writers or some other way?

Comment: You could make a static jsp include of a second text whereto you write the scripts.

Comment: Hey Joop, sorry Im not sure what you mean. Could explain it to me or some psuedo code? Thanks, would be really grateful :)

Comment: On hindsight you deserve a bit more of challenge seeing your ERB/ruby experience. So gave an answer in the MVC tradition.

Comment: You can use simple jsp-based templating. Why are you using your own writers at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish text juggling. As ERB, ruby on rails, also has a bit of Model-View-Controller separation, let's keep the same practice here:

A servlet (the *controller*) builds one or more data *models* and puts them in request attributes. Then it forwards to a JSP (the *view*).

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {

    List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    request.setAttribute("contents", contents);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/contentsview.jsp")
        .forward(request, response);
}
```

As I guess intended to do a loop on data emitting HTML and building a parallel list collected in a StringWriter, this already should solve the problem.

Now for doing (too much) work in the JSP: you can use the JspWriter  also in methods, so order of evaluation is just as free.

```
<%!
     private void printSomething() {
         %><p>...</p><%
     }
%>
```